# How to Sum and Transpose Dataframe Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe that looks like this:

```
              M                        V            
     2019-07-11  2019-04-13   2019-07-11  2019-04-14
NI            1           2            4           9
```

I want the output to only sum values for `M`, and then separately for `V`, where each is added as a new row to a separate Dataframe, like so:

```
  | Total
----------
M |   3
----------
V |  13
----------
```

So how can I sum `M` and `V`separately, and add each as its own row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data, df as:

```
            M                     V           
   2019-07-11 2019-04-13 2019-07-11 2019-04-14
NI          1          2          4          9
```

Then you can use:

```
df.T.sum(level=0)
```

Or

```
df.groupby(df.columns.get_level_values(0), axis=1).sum().T
```

Output:

```
   NI
M   3
V  13
```

---

Try groupby by axis=1 on partial column names using str get or split:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Unnamed: 0')
df1.groupby(df1.columns.str[0], axis=1).sum().T
```

Or more generic for more characters in column

```
df1.groupby(df1.columns.str.split('.').str[0], axis=1).sum().T
```

Output:

```
Unnamed: 0  NI
M            3
V           13
```

where df is:

```
  Unnamed: 0  M  M.1  V  V.1
0         NI  1    2  4    9
```

Comment: In the actual csv file, the columns have the same name. So two columns are ```V``` and two are ```M```. I don't really know why it makes ```M.1``` and ```V.1``` when converting to df.

Comment: When you read csvs with duplicate columns it mangles them to create unique column and with the dot suffix added. .1 .2 .3 etc.. for each occurance after the first.

Comment: Ah I see, I guess that's part of the problem. I re-stated the original question, so hopefully it's easier to work with now.

Answer (score 1):

You can check `sum`

```
df.sum(level=0,axis=1).sum()
Out[129]: 
M     3
V    13
dtype: int64
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to return the desired output

Comment: Thanks, that's closer but I still see separate rows for both values of ```M``` and ```V```, when they should be summed like in the output in your answer.

Comment: Maybe has something to do with reading from a csv, as I get this error: ```FutureWarning: The signature of `Series.to_csv` was aligned to that of `DataFrame.to_csv`, and argument 'header' will change its default value from False to True: please pass an explicit value to suppress this warning.```

Comment: @MSD your sample data is different , the column name changed

Comment: Sorry, it might be an issue with reading from the csv file. I'll try to clean this up

Comment: eliminated the csv file from the equation and the df looks different now, so I updated the original code. Sorry for the confusion